# How do I prevent SVN from caching credentials for a single repository?

Tags: svn, version-control, collabnet

I'm using Collabnet SVN client versions 1.5 & 1.6. My local machine is running Windows Vista x64 (I know, very sad indeed). I would like to force authentication every time I try to perform any subversion operations on a selected repository. How might I set a property or setting to require authentication every time? Thanks for the help and suggestions!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have 2 Solutions:

1. use the **--no-auth-cache** switch on **all** of your commands
2. edit the Subverison config file (%APPDATA%\Subversion\config )and look for commented line:

# store-passwords = no

and remove the "#" at start of the line. This will switch off Password caching permanently.

Comment: Great handle btw (I'm a reader of Spiderman). If that's your real name even better. So I couldn't find the Subversion\config folder, but let's say I have a working copy that I want to apply --no-auth-cache to all .svn directories recursively. Would you know how to accomplish this. 

I marked this as answered, b/c I'm clearly missing something that everyone else seems to know as confirmed by their extremely similar answers LOL.

Comment: `config` is a file not a folder; on Vista it should be at `C:\Users\mkelley\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\config`.

Don't forget to clear the cache files first; otherwise, if your password has already been cached, it will remain cached even if you set `store-passwords = no`.

And `--no-auth-cache` is not a property of a folder, but rather an option that you pass when you execute a command.  If you set `store-passwords = no`, you won't need it.

Comment: also check for a .subversion folder in %USERPROFILE%, and my config file on Win 7 is at %APPDATA%\Roaming\Subversion\conig

Comment: Thanks (Michael and James) for the clarification, and of course my web-slinging answer-provider (Peter Parker) for providing a great answer.

Answer (score 5):

You want the `--no-auth-cache` option.