# SVN / Jenkins / MAVEN - Authentication Problems

Tags: svn, maven-2, maven, jenkins

I have some problems on svn authentication with jekins and maven.

Here are the steps of my work :

- I install Jenkins on a new machine (linux Cent OS).
- I declare 2 jobs into jenkins.
- First job chechout application from svn url https://mydomain.com/myProject1/trunk, i configure credentials for this url with : user1/pwd1
- 2nd job chechout application from svn url https://mydomain.com/myProject2/trunk, i configure credentials for this url with : user2/pwd2

At this time no Problem, all builds are OK.

Now one developper tell me that when he want to use jenkin's menu entry : "Perform Maven Release", he's got the following error "/bin/sh: svn: command not found".
I tell me that jenkins for doing builds use his own svn plugin but maven look for a real svn client install on the machnine.

- So i install a svn client on this machine

Now my problem is that i can't use both snv users user1 and user2 at the same time.
I have SVNAuthenticationException.

When i do a manual chekout of project1 with user1, all my builds for project 1 are ok but builds for poject2 are KO.
And the inverse is right too, i do a manual checkout of project2 with user2, here builds for project2 are ok and builds for project1 are KO.

I think credentials are save or in a cache on the machine (svn client side) when i do the manual checkout and after that, jenkins use them to builds All the projects.

Have you ever see that problem ? have you a solution ?

Any help is appreciate.

Thanks by advance.

--

Loïc

Comment: Perhaps you could create a readOnly SVN account for both the projects to be used by jenkins?

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want to disable svn's caching of client credentials.  E.g., use the "--no-auth-cache" switch on *all* of your commands. (Can also be done by changing svn config.)

Don't forget to clear the already-existing cache files ( ~/.subversion/auth or Windows... maybe "Documents and Settings/%User%/Applications/Subversion/auth").

See also:

- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html
- [How do I prevent SVN from caching credentials for a single repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657602/how-do-i-prevent-svn-from-caching-credentials-for-a-single-repository)